# PHP API send email does nothing via Mandril

Tags: php, mandrill

I am sending a message based on the php example in the docs. Looking through others suggestions I have altered the sending part as follows ..

```
$async = false;
$ip_pool = null;
$send_at = null;
$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
print_r($result);
```

I get a valid result ...

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => valid-email@gmail.com [status] => queued [_id] => 845a02f92f03487f95ff9bc5b5e33497 ) )
```

When I check the API logs it says the message was sent BUT if I try a ..

```
   $result = $mandrill->messages->info($id);
```

With the correct ID I get a result of no message found.

I can send an email using the mandril test page

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Can't remember for sure but I think I copied the code verbatim and it included an attachment, or some other dependent items. Mandrill said it was successful when in fact it wasn't.